# plotting polygons in python using geopandas and folium

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to plot polygons based on site 'regions'. I want a line that goes around the outside of a region to define it's perimeter.

Here is my code:

```
#Import the source data and libraries
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
df = pd.read_csv('tacs.csv')

#Extract the lat long lists from the datasource
lat_point_list = df['magnet.latitude'].tolist()
lon_point_list = df['magnet.longitude'].tolist()

#Some wizardry
polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom])       

#output to files
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")

#plot on a map with central point being birmingham
m = folium.Map([51.509865, -0.118092], zoom_start=12, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

The issue is, it comes out like the below. It's not a line around the perimeter, rather a big mess of interconnecting points.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is an atribute called [convex_hull](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.convex_hull). According to this documentation:

> GeoSeries.convex_hull Returns a GeoSeries of geometries representing
>   the convex hull of each geometry.
>
> The convex hull of a geometry is the smallest convex Polygon
>   containing all the points in each geometry, unless the number of
>   points in the geometric object is less than three. For two points, the
>   convex hull collapses to a LineString; for 1, a Point.

Here is an example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 48.853033, 52.518172, 50.072651, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 2.349553, 13.407759, 14.435935, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon_geom2 = polygon_geom.convex_hull # the atribute
import folium
m = folium.Map([50.854457, 4.377184], zoom_start=5, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(polygon_geom).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(polygon_geom2).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

Answer (score 2):

A convex hull of a non-convex polygon is not the perimeter. One way of doing this (there is probably a better way) is to recast the polygon as a LinearRing:

```
#a polygon:
R = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[1,2],[2,3],[3,2],[1,2]])
#cast as linearring:
L = shapely.geometry.LinearRing(R.exterior.coords)
```

Then you can replace the geometry column of Polygons in you geodataframe with a geometry column of LinearRings/LineStrings, and plot those instead.